# Why Night Light not working in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, settings, ubuntu-20.04

**When I try to set it up the Night Light, nothing happens**. Has anybody met such problem? Please, help with solving.

Before I restarted my laptop it was working normally. But, after restarting, even I couldn't open the settings display. Then I tried these commands:
"sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall
gnome-control-center", after what display settings opened. Unfortunately, there is no response to my setting from display.

I tried to find the answer in askubuntu.com, but they're directing me to ask from ubuntu server: "apport-collect 1880739"

P.S. Before restarting I had uninstalled MySql with the following commands:
"sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql"
Might it be the cause of the problem?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  or [sf], but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com is still probably the best fit, even though you already checked there.